# regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

using http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html I tested the following regex

```
 ^\\{1}([0-9])+
```

this is designed to match a backslash and then a number.

It works there

If I then try this directly in code

```
var reg = /^\\{1}([0-9])+/;
reg.exec("/123")
```

I get no matches!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't that a forward slash in the second line?

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using match(), https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:String:match ?

Comment: actually I was being an idiot.

I wanted to match /123
so I needed something like 

/^\/{1}([0-9]+)$/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in your string:

```
"\\123"
```

Also, for various implementation bugs, you may want to set `reg.lastIndex = 0;`.
In addition, `{1}` is completely redundant, you can simplify your regex to `/^\\(\d)+/`.
One last note: `(\d)+` will only capture the *last digit*, you may want `(\d+)`.

Comment: @lehelp - Your post still shows without the ` \ `, right now your `reg.exec("\123")` is escaping the `1`, not acting as a backslash. - Wow didn't realize I had to escape it in the damn comment as well heh.

Comment: @Nick: The typo was a `/` instead of `\ ` (see sje397's comment). Kobi updated his answer in the meantime.

Comment: You were right the first time.

I actually WANTED to test /123

my regex was testing \123

:)

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

Regarding the update of your question. Then the regex has to be:

```
var reg = /^\/(\d+)/;
```

You have to escape the slash inside the regex with `\/`.

---

The backslash needs to be escaped in the string too:

```
reg.exec("\\123")
```

Otherwise `\1` will be treated as special character.

Btw, the regular expression can be simplified:

```
var reg = /^\\(\d+)/;
```

Note that I moved the quantifier `+` **inside** the capture group, otherwise it will only capture a single digit (namely `3`) and not the whole number `123`.

Comment: @Anders - if you don't want to capture, you can use `^\\\d+` - you don't need a group at all.